# Registering a java application as the default browser in Windows 10

Tags: java, browser, windows-10, registry

I am writing a java application, which can handle standard links (`http`/`https`).

How can I register my application as the default program opening these links (aka default browser) in Windows 10?

I know I can select the default browser in the windows settings, but it only shows a limited list, no way to hook up a custom program.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043664/how-do-i-set-a-python-program-as-the-default-web-browser-in-windows), but it only shows how to do it pre-win10, plus I'm not sure it can be done in java.

Comment: It looks like only Microsoft Store apps can be added to the default programs dropdown list. Still you can set programs to file types and protocols individually as shown in [this article](https://techforluddites.com/windows-10-change-the-default-programs-for-opening-files/).

Comment: As @Rashin said I think you need to go throw the app store. Also, the link below shows how to build a custom browser (by Microsoft dev team) and they write the same there. https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/27/creating-your-own-browser-with-html-and-javascript/

Comment: Doesn't this help in W10 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671277/how-do-i-register-a-custom-application-as-a-web-browser-in-windows-8-1 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865703/how-can-i-programatically-set-the-default-browser-in-windows-10

Comment: @Rashin I don't think that is true, as firefox is part of that list and wasn't installed through the app store.

Comment: @TarunLalwani that doesn't work on windows 10. (I just tested and confirmed it isn't working)

Comment: Don't have windows 10 to confirm for you. Will see if I give something else

Comment: @TarunLalwani I figured it out. Windows 10 has some more restrictions, but the baseline is the same as in your first linked post (see my answer). Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you in solving your issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The application needs to be packaged as an `exe`.

I used [launch4j](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j) for this. Make sure `textVersion` and `icon` is set.

2. A lot of registry keys need to be created. I've pieced those together by looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671277/how-do-i-register-a-custom-application-as-a-web-browser-in-windows-8-1) (kindly linked by [@Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani)), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426870/how-to-add-my-protocol-into-default-programs-in-windows-10?rq=1), and the registry entries created by firefox. This means some of them might not be necessary.

**Register client**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\MyApp\Capabilities]
'ApplicationDescription'='MyApp'
'ApplicationIcon'='C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe,0'
'ApplicationName'='MyApp'

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\MyApp\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
'http'='MyAppURL'
'https'='MyAppURL'

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\MyApp\DefaultIcon]
@='C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe,0'

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\MyApp\shell\open\command]
@='C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe'
```

**Register url handler**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MyAppURL]
@='MyApp Document'
'EditFlags'=0x2
'FriendlyTypeName'='MyApp Document'
'URL Protocol'=''

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MyAppURL\DefaultIcon]
@='C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe,0'

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MyAppURL\shell]
@='open'

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\MyAppURL\shell\open\command]
@='"C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" --url "%1"'
```

**Register to default programs**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
'MyApp'='Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\MyApp\Capabilities'
```

3. Now the application can be selected in the windows settings

Comment: would this work for any other type of program? Like not a browser, but something else that could open custom files?

Comment: @Dahlin this specifically registers the application as an url handler. For files I'd expect a similar approach to work, but the exact registry keys necessary are most likely different.

Comment: oke thanks! But also, how would the registry keys be created, not via launch4j I guess?

Comment: @Dahlin I created them manually via regedit. Not sure how one would automate it, that would be another question.

Comment: I have done that before, Advapi32 can do that for example, requires admin privileges though, I just thought there would be an easier way